# SVG mask on canvas still doesn't work on FF

Tags: svg, firefox, mask, clip-path, clipping

For a website, I'm trying to add a mask to a processing.js canvas. In Chrome it works, I have a responsive mask using SVG. But in Firefox all my canvas disapears. I know that the were problems with clipping mask in Firefox, but as I understood it's now OK to use clipping mask on FF. So I don't know were is the probleme.

Here is my code :

HTML :

```
 <canvas class=" processing-intro" data-processing-sources="intro.pde"></canvas>

 <div class="svg-container">
  <svg width="100%" >
   <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping"  >
     <rect  class="col-12 rect-cache" width="1280" height="35vw" />
    </clipPath>
   </defs>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

CSS :

```
 .processing-intro{
 clip-path: url(#clipping);
 }
```

Any ideas ? Thank you !

Comment: I've pasted your code into a file and I'm honestly unsure what I'm looking at.  Could you include more of your code, (perhaps in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/)), so we can run the example and see what you're seeing, and understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Where's your CSS? Is it a separate file? You do know that url(#x) is a shorthand for url(this file#x) and that your clipping element is not in your CSS file.